# In the java code example, what is the reference and what is the value?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Lets get the terminology straight once and for all. I have been confused about all the conflicting vocabulary online relating to passing by reference and value.

Below is an easy clean example of passing an object argument to a method.
The result is that Mike Grant's name is butchered as well as his age. So the underlying object was changed.

2 Major questions:

- What is the **value**, and what is the **reference**?
- Would the **hashcode** be different of `p1` once the `changePersonObject()` method is run on it?

My code:

```
public class App {      
    public void changePersonObject(Person p){
        p.setAge(100);
        p.setFirstName("Lost");
        p.setLastName("Boy");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        App a = new App();
        Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Grant", 24, 180);               
        a.changePersonObject(p1);
        System.out.println(p1); // person objects name is changed to "Lost"
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is never pass by reference, it is always pass by value. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/504685

Comment: 1)p1 is the reference, 2) probably we have to see Person class

Comment: unless we can see how the hashcode is generated, then it is impossible to answer the second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Grant", 24, 180);
```

creates a new object of type `Person` and assigns the value of its reference to the variable p1.

Java is pass by value. That means that a **copy of the value** used as an argument is bound to the parameter of the method.

The expression

```
a.changePersonObject(p1);
```

is passing `p1` as an argument to the invocation of the `changePersonObject` method. A copy of the value of `p1` which is the reference to an object is therefore bound to the parameter `p` in

```
public void changePersonObject(Person p){
    p.setAge(100);
    p.setFirstName("Lost");
    p.setLastName("Boy");
}
```

In the method itself, `p` is referencing the same object as `p1` in `main`. So when you dereference it by invoking a method such as

```
 p.setAge(100);
```

you're affecting the same object.

If instead you did

```
p = new Person("Soto", "Deli", 24, 42);// whatever arguments
```

The variable `p` now has a new value, the value of the reference to a new `Person` object. This will not affect `p1` in `main` in any way.

> would the hashcode be different of p1 once the changePersonObject()
>   method is run on it?

If you haven't implemented a `hashcode` method in `Person`, then the value returned will be the same regardless of you changing the value of the instance's fields.

Comment: If it was pass by reference, changing the reference in the method invoked would affect the reference from the invoking code. It doesn't. Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Comment: Okay, but in your answer above, what is a value and what is the reference? You are referring to the vocabulary VALUE and REFERENCE as if I know what those are.. Can you please elaborate. Thanks for your help

Comment: @TazMan The reference to the object is its memory address. We never see that in Java. The value of the reference is the value of the reference, eg. something like `0x0001234`.

Comment: So then what is p1? its a variable that points to what? Isn't that the reference? Its pointing to the value of 0x0001234??\

Comment: @Taz So `p1` is a variable that stores the value of the reference, ie. something like `0x00001234`. The act of dereferencing the variable, ie. calling a method like `p1.someMethod()` is what actually accesses the object.

Comment: p1.someMethod() access what object?

Comment: @TazMan `someMethod()` is invoked on the object that `p1` is referencing.

Comment: @TazMan: `p1` is a variable of type `Person`, a reference type. So we can say `p1`'s value is a reference (pointer to an object). It points to an object.

Answer (score 4):

Java is pass-by-value indeed, but actually the one that hold this value is little bit of different with what you might think of.  [java is pass by value?](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)
the word `value`, which in basic data type is the data itself, for instance

```
int numberA=100  ;
int numberB=numberA;
```

the value that passed from `numberA` to `numberB` is the data `100`.
things never change in `Reference type`:

```
Person p = new Person("Lost", "Boy", 24);
Person person=p;
person=new Person("Rugal", "Bernstein", 23);
```

the value that is passed from `p` to `person` is the reference address that point to the `Person("Lost", "Boy", 24)` one, for any details please execute program above and debug it yourself to clarify them.
Here you might think, after `person=new Person("Rugal", "Bernstein", 23);` the value of person now is disparate with its original one. yes of course, now if you `println(person)` and that will turn out to be a new Person as you might think of.
But what about `p`, does that changed because Java is pass-by-value?
Actually, after test with that, I found it is not, even if you changed the `person`, it will not bother `p`. what's wrong with java, is there any problem here ?

Yes, java demonstrated there is no pointer in it and all the things that passed in parameter is called `reference`. lets go back to C/C++ style of programming:

```
int data=100,temp=50;
int* pdata=&data;
int& rdata=data;

pdata=&temp;
println（"%d  %d",*pdata,rdata）；

rdata=temp;
println（"%d  %d",*pdata,rdata）；
```

anything special can you find from above?
yes, actually in C/C++ , there is two type of so call `pass-by-value` method, the first one declared by `*` is called `pointer`, second one start with `&` named `reference`, here please do not consider this reference with java, because you will find they are different later.
in C/C++ , the `reference` is a kind of `alias`, in other word, these two variables are totally identical thing, whatever changes you made on one will thus effect the other one. because they are just one thing.
But `Pointer` is a little different with `reference`. yes pointer can also point to a variable and you can also change the value of that variable by using `*pdata=temp`. But here is a problem, when you using `pdata=&temp` to change the pointer itself, will the `data` change according to `pdata`?
the answer is NO!
you can test it yourself ! because what value store in pointer is the address of `data` variable, when you want to change the value of `data` it can surely change it by refer `*`, but when you try to change the address that stored in `pdata` it would not bother with `data` because they are totally different two variable.
Now do you have a familiar sense that you have ever feel this before?

### yes, in java the so called `reference` is what `pointer` behave like in C/C++.

and here we have the deal, in java that demonstrated itself with `pass-by-value` is correct and `no more pointer` is a mendacity.

now let me answer questions:

1.the word value is the data that stored in memory. in java primitive type hold real data as value and address as value in reference type.

2.as I have already explained above, you can test it yourself!

3.and I tested some code, the `hashcode（）`  will not change so long as the value of your object do not change.
for instance:

```
Person p = new Person("Lost", "Boy", 24);//Hash Code 38443066
p.setAge(100);  //Hash Code 38443066
p=new Person("Rugal", "Bernstein", 23);//Hash Code 38444526
```

because in default situation, `hashcode()` method only measure the address itself hence so long as your address unchanged, the `hashcode()` will not change.
you can override this method by yourself to measure its member fields as well.
the method `changePersonObject()` only changed the member field in it thus will have no difference with outer `hashcode()`. you can achieve it by `person=new Person("Rugal", "Bernstein", 23);`  in this method, its `hashcode()` will surely changed.

please try it and you will get more comprehension with Java

Comment: +1 I think that's the longest correct answer I've ever seen from a new user. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Java only supports pass by value, not pass by reference. (References to objects are passed by value). For more information please see the following: http://javachannel.net/wiki/pmwiki.php/FAQ/PassingVariables, http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html, and http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm?repost

Answer (score 0):

1. p1 = new Person("Mike", "Grant", 24, 180); <-- the "value" of the Object person is the Object, p1 is the "reference" to that Person object
2. Yes. If Person implements hashCode() correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when comparing with other languages, the meaning of `pass by value` and `pass by value` is slightly different.

In your example, the fact that you can change the `values` of `p1` in a method may make you believe that you are passing by reference - this is not the case in Java.

To illustrate, that this is passing by value

```
public class App {

public void changePersonObject(Person p){

    p = new Person("Lost", "Boy", 24, 100);  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    App a = new App();
    Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Grant", 24, 180);               
    a.changePersonObject(p1);
    System.out.println(p1); // person objects name is still "Mike"
 }
}
```

Unless we can see how the hashcode is generated, then it is impossible to answer the second question.  If it is not implemented in Person, then it is likely that the value returned will be the same regardless of you changing the value of the instance's fields.

Comment: Woah, this is confusing. So why was I able to change the underlying components of p1 (name, age, etc..) when passing it to `changePersonObject()`? I don't get that part... The way I see it is, when you pass p1 to the method, it gets reset! p1 should be pointing to a new object with Lost and Boy, not Mike Grant..

Comment: I believe that the underlying JVM technology is that when an object is passed to a method, a copy of it is made and put on the stack.  The values can be changed, but the reference to the Object can not.  Thats is you can not change to where the object points (as in a C++ pass by reference)

Comment: The meaning of "pass by value" and "pass by reference" is the same regardless of language. That's the point -- if a term that describes languages meant different things in different languages, it would be useless.